# PL/SQL Update where current of

Tags: plsql, cursor, sql-update, where-clause

I need to raise price of a book by 5% if publisher is 'x' and by 10% for others. I need to do it using 'where current of' and 'returning into' clause.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE publisher = 'x';
CURSOR c2 IS SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE publisher != 'x';
BEGIN
UPDATE books SET price = price + 0.05 * price WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
UPDATE books SET price = price + 0.1 * price WHERE CURRENT OF c2;
END;
```

Is there simplier way than doing two cursors and two updates with something like 'when others'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and straight..

```
UPDATE books SET price =decode(publisher,'x'
                               ,price + 0.05 * price  -- If 'x'
                               ,price + 0.1 * price); -- else
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make a simple thing more complex? Just do:

```
UPDATE books SET price = price + 0.05 * price WHERE publisher = 'x';
UPDATE books SET price = price + 0.1 * price WHERE publisher != 'x'
```